# IOS - how to set image in UIview

Tags: ios, github, uiimageview

I'm working with this project
[IOS-Image-Swiper](https://github.com/tim-woo/IOS-Image-Swiper)

and I'm trying to set images in the view with no success.

```
    self.photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"],
             nil];
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your question is not clear, give more detail

Comment: You say you are trying to set images in the view…how are you doing that?  (You show an array, not a view.)

Comment: You mentioned above project is somewhat different approach. You have to refer whole code in that project. They written custom view with gestures. And, what's your need tell that clearly?

Comment: I solved the issue by ' 
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        card.front.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
self.imgView.animationImages =  @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"],];
```

Comment: take up vote from my side sir. @Mayank Jain

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
        UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage : 
              [UIImage imageNamed :@“uiimage.png"]];
        UIView *myUIView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame :CGRectMake(0,10,20,40)]; 
        myUIView = myImageView;
```

OR:

```
   UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uiimage.png"]];
  [self addSubview:background];
  [self sendSubviewToBack:background];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, Hope it'll help you..

```
NSArray * imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple5.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"], nil];

imageView.animationImages = imageArray;
imageView.animationDuration = 4;
[imageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```